# Angular 2 auth guard - my app needs to first authenticate before loading any of the routes. How do I handle this?

Tags: angular

Basically, here's how my `AppComponent`'s `app.component.html` (my bootstrap component) looks:

```
<navigation-top>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In my `AppComponent`'s `ngOnInit` I'm calling my authentication service which returns me a token.  I need this token to send with each API request I make.

```
if (!tokenNotExpired()) {
  this.authService.login()
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      const key = data.headers.get('Authorization');
      this.key = key;
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', key);
    }
  );
} else {
  this.key = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
}
```

However, I am also adding a Auth Guard to my `app.routes.ts` so that `router-outlet` only loads components once I have a token.

However, I'm not sure the best way to approach this problem.  If I put my call to get a token in `AppComponent`, then at the start my Auth Guard will return false if I don't have a key at all, and thus nothing will load.

How can I set up my logic so that I wait for the key?

Comment: If you have some kind of sitemap that you must download to allow navigations, you will need to add the definitions(array of routes) to the router after that call.

Comment: @user1354934, how did you solve this?